# Is there a way to prevent alternate characters from being inserted by OSX's Long Press character menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, macos

I'm working on a structured input class in JavaScript that handles keydown/keypress events to ensure that only certain types of input are allowed in certain fields (for example, a number cannot be inserted into an alphabetic-only field).  My structured input will throw out invalid characters before they make it to the input field.

I recently discovered that on OSX, if you hold down certain keys for a short interval, you're presented with a popup menu of alternate options for that key (like long-pressing the `U` key presents you with options like `û`, `ü`, etc).  If you choose one of these options from the popup menu and you're focused on an input field being watched by my structured input class, the character is inserted into the field regardless of whether or not the character is valid.

[image: Long Press Menu is Open by holding "U"]  [image: Alternate character inserted]

From what I can tell, this is happening because the OS is simply adding the character and not triggering any normal JavaScript events you would expect to fire when keying in text (`keydown`, `keypress`, `keyup`).  However, the Input and Change events are fired.  I considered listening to the input event to remove these non-standard characters, but since the character entered is not included inside the Input event (there is no `e.which`, `e.keycode`, `e.charCode`), I'd be required to do a lot of additional analysis on the content of the input field that I'm trying to avoid.

My question is, are there any events being fired that I'm not aware of that I can use to accurately capture the Mac OSX Long-Pressed Character Popup?  Or am I out of luck?

**EDIT:**  I've added an example of how I'm currently checking for keyboard events for reference.

The event listeners in the constructor:

```
    // Point all keyboard related events to the handleKeyEvents() method, which knows how to
    // deal with key syphoning and event propogation.
    self.element.on('keydown.mask keypress.mask ' + self.env.pasteEvent, null, function(e) {
      self.handleKeyEvents(self, e);
    });
```

And the actual key handling method:

```
// The catch-all event for handling keyboard events within this input field. Grabs information about the keys
// being pressed, event type, matching pattern characters, and determines what to do with them.
  handleKeyEvents: function(self, e) {
    var evt = e || window.event,
      eventType = evt.originalEvent.type,
      key = e.which,
      typedChar = String.fromCharCode(key);

    // set the original value if it doesn't exist.
    if (!self.initValue) {
      self.initValue = self.element.val();
    }

    if (eventType === 'keydown') {
      // backspace || delete
      if (key === 8 || key === 46 || (self.env.iPhone && key === 127)) {
        self.handleBackspace(evt);
      } else if (key === 13) { // enter
        self.element.trigger('blur', evt);
      } else if (key === 27) { // escape
        self.handleEscape(evt);
      } else if (36 < key && key < 41) { // arrow keys (in Firefox)
        return;
      } else if (evt.shiftKey && 36 < key && key < 41) { // arrow keys AND shift key (for moving the cursor)
        return;
      }
    }

    if (eventType === 'keypress') {
      // Ignore all of these keys or combinations containing these keys
      if (evt.ctrlKey || evt.altKey || evt.metaKey || key < 32) {
        return;
      // Need to additionally check for arrow key combinations here because some browsers
      // Will fire keydown and keypress events for arrow keys.
      } else if (evt.shiftKey && 36 < key && key < 41 && typedChar !== '(') {
        return;
      } else if ((36 < key && key < 41) && typedChar !== '\'' && typedChar !== '(')  {
        // '(' is keycode 40 on some browsers
        // '/' is keycode 39 on some browsers
        return;
      }
      if (self.mode === 'number') {
        self.processNumberMask(typedChar, evt);
      } else {
        self.processMask(typedChar, evt);
      }
    }

    if (eventType === 'paste') {
      self.handlePaste(evt);
    }
```

Comment: Note that prior to OS X.7 (Lion), Mac users could input special characters via combinations with the `option` key (e.g. `option u u` produces `ü`). How is your code for the input-check currently written?

Comment: Thanks for the info, I wasn't aware of that.  I've added some code examples showing how my keys are handled, and as you can see I don't currently check for the option key.  I'll be adding support in for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend doing an extra check on the validity of the fields before actually submitting the content. This way non-OSX users will get the intended experience but in the event that this long-press behavior occurs, you can still catch it before it's submitted.

Another option would be to periodically check the contents of the field using `setInterval`

I know it sounds like duplicating logic but without consistent input methods it would be impossible to write a generic solution.

Comment: This is really good advice and something I'd intended on doing anyway.  However, my main concern from a UX standpoint was trying to prevent bad input from ever reaching the field in the first place.

Comment: @EdwardCoyleJr. - Apple decided to trash a unified UX experience when they implemented their alternative input methods so...yea.. Now their users will have to deal with the consequences. I'm glad you found my answer helpful :)

Comment: I did!  I'm sorry I can't upvote you because of my lousy reputation but I promise I will as soon as possible.

Comment: @EdwardCoyleJr. - I see you're making an effort to edit and refine your post so I've helped you down the path for some imaginary internet points of your very own! Use them responsibly!

Comment: haha!  Thank you!  I promise not to waste these valuable internet points!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do this client side, you can use **input masks** for the fields. There are a number of solutions out there like:

- **[jQuery Input Mask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask)** (very robust)
- [Jasny Bootstrap Input Mask](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#inputmask)
- [jQuery Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

They allow you to "mask" the input to whatever criteria you define or use presets like *alphanumeric*, *numeric*, *alphabetical*, etc. These masks prevent users from entering characters not defined within the mask at each index. There are even callbacks for further customization.

Comment: I'm actually building that exact type of functionality as part of my class.  We're building it-in house instead of using the libraries due to some special requirements.  I just double checked the Bootstrap and jQuery Masked Input, and they do handle this problem but at a glance it appears they do it on `input` or `change`.  jQuery Input Mask also handles it but they don't seem to leave existing characters in place correctly.

These links are good for reference though, I'll scour the source and see how they do it.